# Display two fields in a single line in laravel nova with vite

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I just started work on the laravel 9 and using Nova along with vite(not using webpack.mix.js).

Laravel Nova works great and I created many resources, it just works great, but I am wondering how can I align the two or more nova fields in a single line on the Nova form.

For example First Name and Last Name! Can we display or align these two fields in a single line instead of two separate lines?

Please suggest me your ideas and references

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want [a computed field](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields).

Comment: No @ceejayoz, I am especially talking about showing multiple fields in a row on the "Form"

Comment: Not built-in. https://nova-fields.netlify.app/custom.html#row may help.

Answer (score 0):

In some projects we have we're using these packages:

https://novapackages.com/packages/outl1ne/nova-simple-repeatable

https://github.com/64robots/nova-row

Hopefully it helps!